# Linq Join and GroupBy refactor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I think I have done a query very repetitive and I was wondering if you can help me to understand how to do it better. I am doing a `Join` and `GroupBy` depending on the `EnumDateFilter`. Can you help me please shorten the code as possible?

Thanks a lot!

```
foreach (Client client in listClient){
    var books = _servBook.GetBooks(BeginDate, EndDate, ClientId).ToList();

    switch (enumDateFilter)
    {
        case EnumDateFilter.Today:
        case EnumDateFilter.OneDay:
            {
                books.Join(
                    dates,
                    bk => new { bk.Date.Hour, bk.Date.Day, bk.Date.Month, bk.Date.Year },
                    cd => new { cd.Date.Hour, cd.Date.Day, cd.Date.Month, cd.Date.Year },
                    (bk, chart) => new { bk, chart.Data }
                )
                .GroupBy(a => new
                {
                    a.bk.Date.Hour,
                    a.bk.Date.Day,
                    a.bk.Date.Month,
                    a.bk.Date.Year,
                    a.Data
                })
                .Select(
                    a =>
                    {
                        a.Key.Data[client.Name] = a.Count().ToString();
                        return a;
                    }
                ).ToList();
            }
            break;

        case EnumDateFilter.OneWeek:
        case EnumDateFilter.OneMonth:
        case EnumDateFilter.LastWeek:
        case EnumDateFilter.LastMonth:
            {
                books.Join(
                    dates,
                    bk => new { bk.Date.Day, bk.Date.Month, bk.Date.Year },
                    cd => new { cd.Date.Day, cd.Date.Month, cd.Date.Year },
                    (bk, chart) => new { bk, chart.Data }
                )
                .GroupBy(a => new
                {
                    a.bk.Date.Day,
                    a.bk.Date.Month,
                    a.bk.Date.Year,
                    a.Data
                })
                .Select(
                    a =>
                    {
                        a.Key.Data[client.Name] = a.Count().ToString();
                        return a;
                    }
                ).ToList();

                break;
            }

        case EnumDateFilter.ThreeMonths:
        case EnumDateFilter.SixMonths:
        case EnumDateFilter.OneYear:
        case EnumDateFilter.LastThreeMonths:
        case EnumDateFilter.LastSixMonths:
        case EnumDateFilter.LastYear:
            {
                books.Join(
                    dates,
                    bk => new { bk.Date.Month, bk.Date.Year },
                    cd => new { cd.Date.Month, cd.Date.Year },
                    (bk, chart) => new { bk, chart.Data }
                )
                .GroupBy(a => new
                {
                    a.bk.Date.Month,
                    a.bk.Date.Year,
                    a.Data
                })
                .Select(
                    a =>
                    {
                        a.Key.Data[client.Name] = a.Count().ToString();
                        return a;
                    }
                ).ToList();
                break;
            }

        case EnumDateFilter.SinceBeginning:
            {
                books.Join(
                    dates,
                    bk => new { bk.Date.Year },
                    cd => new { cd.Date.Year },
                    (bk, chart) => new { bk, chart.Data }
                )
                .GroupBy(a => new
                {
                    a.bk.Date.Year,
                    a.Data
                })
                .Select(
                    a =>
                    {
                        a.Key.Data[client.Name] = a.Count().ToString();
                        return a;
                    }
                ).ToList();
                break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with “replace by expressions”?

Comment: Lambda Expression, but i am not sure if it is possible

Comment: For what purpose though? What do you think lambda expressions allow you to do here?

Comment: please post your code that makes sense. You call `ToList()` in each case without using the result at all. That does not make sense.

Comment: The things is that im reapiting the query in every case of the switch, it is mostly the same. I thought it could be possible to simplify the query. Maybe you have some recomendations

Comment: it should be simplified but should keep the basic logic, someone here may even help you further shorten the code if possible.

Comment: Why does the code does not make sence for you, Hopeless? Have you seen the Select?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you do this work and then throw it away. The code here could have the entire switch block deleted and the only difference in the outcome is that it would be faster. This is likely not what the real code does.

Comment: and if i delete the switch block how should i replace this:  
a.Key.Data[client.Name] = a.Count().ToString();

Comment: Set only lambdas inside `switch`. Place your query after `switch`: `Join(dates, lambda1, lambda2, lambda3).GroupBy(lambda4).Select(lambda5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With anonymous types, this will be difficult to achieve. You might try to use concrete types for joining and grouping. E.g., you would have to create

```
struct TimeDescriptor{
   public int Year;
   //TODO: Put other fields
}
```

This would then allow you to factor out some of the lambda expressions such as

```
Expression<Func<Book, TimeDescriptor>> bookSelector = b => new TimeDescriptor{Year = b.Date.Year, ...}
Expression<Func<DateType, TimeDescriptor>> dateSelector = d => new TimeDescriptor{Year = d.Date.Year}
```

which you could then use in your LINQ, such as

```
books.Join(dates, bookSelector, dateSelector, ...)
```

Your switch could then be reduced to getting the appropriate selectors, and you can write the main query outside the switch. Example:

```
Expression<Func<Book, TimeDescriptor>> bookSelector;
Expression<Func<DateType, TimeDescriptor>> dateSelector;

switch((enumDateFilter)
{
    case EnumDateFilter.Today:
    case EnumDateFilter.OneDay:
         bookSelector = ...;
         dateSelector = ...;
         break;
    ...
}

return books.Join(dates, bookSelector, dateSelector, ...)
```

I hope this helps you getting some ideas.

Comment: Thanks Ronald for your answer! Helps a lot!